# Right way to get content Item by slug

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orchardcms

I need to get content item by it's url, now I'm using this code:

```
 var item =
     Services.ContentManager.Query<AutoroutePart, AutoroutePartRecord>().Where(
         x => x.DisplayAlias == url)
         .List()
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

But it does not look like "right" way. What is better way?

Comment: Will translate into a sarge-able SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I do it exactly the same way in the [Culture Picker](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.CulturePicker) module.

BTW, as far as I know, `ToLower()` method is not supported by LINQ provider for NHibernate 2.x, which is used currently in Orchard.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't look very nice, it is the perfectly right way to do that.
The `Where` clause is directly translated to SQL so you will end up with a single, nice query.